# Does keeping your carbohydrate intake at 20-25% of your total caloric intake reduce insulin-resistance diseases?

Tags: medical-science, diabetes

From this article [Excess Stomach Acid Mimics Hunger](http://www.nemechekconsultativemedicine.com/?page_id=1415)

> Reducing your carbohydrate intake to 20-25% of your total caloric intake has a dramatic improvement in the diseases arising from insulin resistance as well as improving your neurological functioning.  Your triglyceride and HDL cholesterol levels improve, your blood pressure will be greatly reduced and your blood sugar levels will normalize as your body’s response to insulin to improves.

Does keeping your carbohydrate intake to 20-25% of your total caloric intake reduce insulin-resistance diseases?

Comment: anecdotally, I know several people who were diagnosed as Type II diabetics, and were "undiagnosed" 6-12 months later *merely* on diet change (specifically, reducing or eliminating carb intake)

Comment: It would probably depend on what you're replacing that carbohydrate intake with, and whether your total caloric intake remains the same or changes drastically as a result.